# Get "Page Not Found" After Enabling the Devel Drupal 7 Module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to install the [Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) which requires the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

I've downloaded the Devel module via the **Install new Module** page in Drupal. When I enable the module however, I get redirected to a "Page Not Found" error.

Going to **Reports** > **Recent log messages** shows:

```
page not found  06/14/2017 - 10:23  modules/statistics/statistics.php
page not found  06/14/2017 - 10:23  modules/statistics/statistics.php   
php 06/14/2017 - 10:22  User warning: The following module has moved within...
php 06/14/2017 - 10:22  User warning: The following module has moved within...  
php 06/14/2017 - 10:22  User warning: The following module has moved within...
```

The three PHP messages complain that **devel_node_access**, **devel**, and **devel_generate** have all been moved.

Could this be some form of permission issue?

---

**Edit**
This question has now been asked over at [drupal.stackexchange.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238458/getting-page-not-found-after-enabling-the-devel-module-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in as admin there is no permission issue but for other user please check permission.

Thanks,
Ankush

Comment: The original question was asked over a month ago, so the environment I was working with has changed significantly. As such I cannot test if your solution works. Thanks for your input all the same.